# Include Jade mixins via JavaScript in an Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

In my Express app I have a file containing a lot of useful Jade mixins. I want to use that file across multiple projects therefore I plan on creating an NPM module (self hosted in our company's private registry) which will include this mixins file into every pages rendered (or specific pages only).

**Is there a way to do that from the back-end code (using Express probably) ?** Or are there other approaches I could use ?

Basically I just don't want to end up doing this in every projects :

*layout.jade* :

```
include ../../node_modules/my-custom-module/mixins
```

Which would be ugly.

Comment: You might want to look at how the [nib module](https://github.com/tj/nib) works, as what you are trying to achieve seems similar. Though you may need to use something like `include WiMantisMixins` at the top of the file, which is how nib handles it. You could also setup an option that can be toggled (off by default seems best), where it's automatically included in all Jade files. Again researching how various NPM modules do this seems the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Jade API](http://github.com/jadejs/jade#api) to **compile** the file/view manually, attaching your mixins file with the view before compiling.

```
var jade = require('jade');
var yourJadeMixinStr = fs.readFileSync('..mixins', 'utf8');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var render = res.render;
    res.render = function(view, options){

        var yourJadeViewPath = '../views/' + view + '.jade';
        var yourJadeViewStr = fs.readFileSync(yourJadeViewPath, 'utf8');

        options = extend({}, options, res.locals);
        options.filename = yourJadeViewPath;

        var finalJadeViewStr = yourJadeMixinStr + yourJadeViewStr;
        var html = jade.render(finalJadeViewStr, options);

        res.send(html);
    };
    next();
});
```

`options.filename` is required for relative path for any `include` statements in your view. It also seems to be used for [caching purposes under the hood](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/blob/master/lib/index.js#L294).

If you've used `app.set('views', […])` to pass more than one directories to look into for a view, you'll need to account for that.